# Take a snapshot (picture) of Minecraft world every day on linux server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am looking for a way to take a picture of a part of my Minecraft world automatically every day, server side. Basically my objective is to see a day to day evolution of my town.

Since my town is absolutely not at the spawn point, I would like to configure like that (if possible) :

```
camera_x -200
camera_y 150
camera_z -2100
focus_x -100
focus_y 75
focus_z -2000
```

Is there a tool for that? Or should I run a Minecraft client on my server in some way?

Comment: Here is a list of Minecraft map utilities: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Programs_and_editors/Mapping You could configure one of these to run regularly, and configure a separate script to grab a nightly snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out a way to do that using [overviewer](http://overviewer.org/). It is not an exact rendering like the one I was expecting, but still enough to see the evolution of my map.

Here is my configuration:

```
texturepath = "/[...]/textures.zip"
worlds['myworld'] = '/[...]/minecraft1.10.2/world'
outputdir = '/[...]/www/minecraft'

renders['default'] = {
        'world': 'myworld',
        'title': 'test',
        'crop': (-100, -1800, -400, -2100),
        'rendermode': 'smooth-lighting',
}
```

I then simply put a cronjob on my server to backup the previous render and render a new map `overviewer.py --config [myconfigfile]`.

Based on a discussion with CounterPillow on freenode#overviewer there is a way to render the map as a PNG file using the [following script](https://github.com/overviewer/Minecraft-Overviewer/blob/master/contrib/png-it.py).